# lucimatx wrong hat and tilde symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm using lucimatx with beamer, with `\let\digamma\relax \usepackage{lucimatx}`, and the math is displaying wrong.

For example, `\hat{\beta}` shows theta instead of ^

[image]

similar for `\tilde{y}` that shows lambda instead of ~

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please, show a minimal example of code that shows the issue.

Comment: if you needed `\let\digamma\relax` to load the package it indicates you have conflicting math packages loaded and getting incorrect characters would not be surprising.

Comment: Try this (from https://github.com/pmagwene/latex-templates/blob/master/lucida-beamer-example.tex) in preamble: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\let\digamma\relax
\let\eth\relax
\usepackage[scale=0.85,stdmathitalics=true,stdmathdigits=true,romanfamily=casual]{lucimatx}
`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to comment out a conflicting math package. In my case, I had to comment out `mathptmx`:

```
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

Comment: And that is why we always ask for a minimal example.